# PHP -- How to multiple random numbers?

Tags: php

Very new to coding here. Trying to get five random numbers in a range from -10 to 10 generated at once. I have another .php file in which I use the roll_num function, but I'm trying to avoid writing the function 5 different times.

Here is what I currently have:

```
function roll_num()
{
    for ($result = 0; $result <= 5; $result++)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result = rand(-10, 10);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Looking for the simplest way to write this. Help would be useful as I don't know what I'm doing, and this is for an introductory class lol. The way I'm trying is similar to the class example, so I'd like to keep it about the same so that I can follow alongside the course without getting too lost. (Besides what I need to change, of course!) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the return inside of the for loop. As soon you hit the return command the function will exit returning the current value of the result, with only one element. Your return should be out of the for loop.

Try something like this:

```php
<?php
function roll_num()
{
    $result = []; // result should start empty
    while (count($result) < 5)
    {
        // every step of the loop should add random value to the array
        $result[] = rand(-10, 10);
    }
    // after all random values were pushed, you return once
    return $result;
}
var_export(roll_num());
// http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd35d6d65f763963216423f341a4299ce1cee8fe
```

Comment: Take a look at the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php to better understand how the push to array function works.

Comment: I am getting the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array" when I try this

Comment: You are right. We should not compare the $result with values as 0  and 5. We should compare using the size of the array, fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```php
function roll_num()
{
  $min = -10;
  $max = 10;
  $num = 5;
  $count = 0;
  $return = [];
  while ($count < $num) {
    $return[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
    $return = array_flip(array_flip($return));
    $count = count($return);
  }
  shuffle($return);
  return $return;
}


print_r(roll_num());
```